# Changing songs' chords to Arpeggios

Tags: guitar, theory, chords, arpeggios

I want to know how I change chords to Arpeggios in a song? For example how do you change (Somebody's me) by Enrique from chords to Arpeggios or single notes? Can you show me this or another example as you want?

Answer (score 4):

I'll borrow the arpeggio definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpeggio):

> An arpeggio (Italian: [arˈpeddʒo]) is a musical technique where notes in a chord are played or sung in sequence, one after the other, rather than ringing out simultaneously.

So, let's say you have the C major chord, which consists of the notes C-E-G. If you play these 3 notes together, they will form the chord. If you play them one after the other, they will form an arpeggio.

In an arpeggio, you can also repeat these notes, like C E G C E G C E G.

So, in the song you mentioned, just take all the chords and play the notes one after the other.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking an arpeggio is played in strict note order like a scale, but more informally people use it to describe playing a chord in a broken order rather than all at once. With guitar you can hold a chord and play the notes(strings) in any order and it should sound reasonably ok. All the notes will harmonise.

You want to allow the strings to carry on ringing out rather than ending a note when you play the next one as you would normally do when playing a melody line

As mentioned elsewhere there are countless number of patterns you can play. Generally speaking, the placement of the bass note has a big effect on the overall sound, the higher notes less so. Mostly you will want to establish your chord with the root note in the bass (ie first note played of that chord). Below are 3 example of 8th note picking patterns that you can play with pick or fingers. Hold the chord shape throughout as if you were strumming it but pick the individual strings. These examples use just G D and C chords, but you could apply the same patterns to the chords for any song in 4/4.

```
Example 1 
 G                 D                  C       G   
|-------1-------1-|-------2-------2-|-------0-------1-|
|-----0-------0---|-----3-------3---|-----1-------0---|
|---0-------0-----|---2-------2-----|---0-------0-----|
|-----------------|-0-------0-------|-----------------|
|-----------------|-----------------|-3---------------|
|-3-------3-------|-----------------|---------3-------|


Example 2 - alternating bass
 G                 D                 C        G   
|-------1-------1-|-------2-------2-|-------0-------1-|
|-----0-------0---|-----3-------3---|-----1-------0---|
|---0-------0-----|---2-------2-----|---0-------0-----|
|-----------------|-0---------------|-----------------|
|---------2-------|---------0-------|-3---------------|
|-3---------------|-----------------|---------3-------|

Example 2 - alternating bass on beat 1 and 4
 G                 D                 C        G   
|-------1---------|-------2---------|-------0-------1-|
|-----0---0-------|-----3---3-------|-----1-------0---|
|---0-------0---0-|---2-------2---2-|---0-------0-----|
|-----------------|-0---------------|-----------------|
|-------------2---|-------------0---|-3---------------|
|-3---------------|-----------------|---------3-------|
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://www.classicalguitar.org/freemusic/exercises/Giuliani120.pdf) link for a good resource on arpeggios.

There are literally thousands of picking patterns for arpeggios. As a general rule though instead of strumming or playing the notes of a chord together. (Like this)

[image: CHORDS]

You pick the notes one at a time in some sort of pattern. (Like this)

[image: Arpeggio 1]

(OR this)

[image: Arpeggio 2]

[SOURCE:](http://www.classicalguitar.org/freemusic/exercises/Giuliani120.pdf)